# How to get a latest data from a cell for each person who satisfies the condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which goes like this:

```
Name    Type   Date     Value
-------------------------------- 
Emilia  1   2010-11-02  10
Eva     0   2009-07-05  11
Monica  1   2010-04-22  12
Emilia  0   2011-07-12  13
Monica  1   2012-05-01  14
Eva     1   2006-02-12  15
Monica  0   2004-12-12  16
Emilia  1   2005-11-11  17
Eva     1   2014-02-01  18
Emilia  1   2015-03-11  19
Monica  0   2002-11-28  20
```

What I need is to have a table which shows the list of all women who at the latest date have the type 1, and the value at this date. So the table I want to query for should look like this:

```
Name   Value
------------
Emilia 19
Eva    18
```

So basically I need it to see what is the latest date for each person, then check if the type is 1, and if it is, I need to display the data from Value column.

Please help me, because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't the value for Emilia be 19?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to do this.

```
:with CTE as
(
select *,Row_Number() over(partition by Name order by [Date] desc) RN
From Yourtable
)   
select Name,Value from cte 
where RN=1 and Type = 1
```

Comment: @NoDisplayName, I think `where Type = 1` should be inside CTE. If last row by date has 0 then you will get nothing in result.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Thats the requirement check why `Monica` is rejected in expected output

Comment: @NoDisplayName, yep, my mistake, sorry. By the way change `:with` to `;with`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (name varchar(10),type int,date date, valu int)

insert into @t(name,type,date,valu)values ('Emilia',1,'2010-11-02',10)
insert into @t(name,type,date,valu)values ('Emilia',0,'2015-03-11',10)
insert into @t(name,type,date,valu)values ('Emilia',1,'2015-11-11',19)
insert into @t(name,type,date,valu)values ('Eva',0,'2006-02-12',10)
insert into @t(name,type,date,valu)values ('Eva',1,'2014-02-01',20)

SELECT a.*
FROM @t a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT type,MAX(date) AS LatestDate FROM @t GROUP BY type)b 
ON a.type = b.type
AND a.date=b.LatestDate
```